# Is there a pydantic way to create the schema for a pydantic model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have made a simple pydantic model like this one:

```
class AppRegistry(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    apps: List[AppConfig] = []

class AppConfig(BaseModel):
    name: str
    group: Optional[Union[str, int, list]] = None
```

Now, I would like a way to reuse the model base class to create the schema. Often, before validating your schema you obviously need to have one or create it. I would like to reuse the pydantic model as it already has all the attribute required and do something like that:

```
class AppRegistry(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    apps: List[AppConfig] = []

    def add_application(self, name, group = None):
         # ... do stuff
         self.apps.append(AppConfig(name, group))
```

And use it this way:

```
registry = AppRegistry("main_registry")
registry.add_application("my_app")

# Re validate the model
AppRegistry(**registry.model_dump())
```

For me, this fill a little bit weird and I was wondering if I need to create a special class to create the schema that I want to validate with pydantic ? If yes, it will duplicate the models ?

How do you guys create your schema ?